# Call a function on regex match

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to call a function when an id matches a regex?

I have an app where I have about 20 or so divs calling the same function by onclick and I'm trying to get rid of the onclicks and just find those divs by id.  The divs id's start the same way for instance: sameId_xxx

This is what I have working but I was wondering if I could put the condition in the function call so it's not being called for every div on the page.

```
$("div").click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    if (id.match(/sameId_/)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Some have different classes. Necessity for the design

Comment: Yeah, but you could add another class to them that separates them from the other divs, say `mySpecialKindOfDiv`. This won't interfere with the CSS.

Comment: [`$('div[id^=sameID_]')`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('div[id^="sameId_"]').click(...)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kpcxu/

For more info, see [Attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Thanks. Incorporated into answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try the jQuery 'attribute contains selector':

```
$('div[id*="sameId_"]').click(function() {
// Do stuff
});
```

Comment: As per Shawn Chin's answer above the attribute starts selector would be more accurate

Answer (score 0):

I think better filter all div with using necessary condition and next add handler.

For example:

```
$('div')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).attr('id') % 2 })
        .click(function(){alert($(this).attr('id'))});​
```

Live demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/As53c/)

Or you can use `var id = $(this).attr('id')` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers (with filtering on the id up front) are better, but for posterity, here is what you actually asked for:

```
$("div").click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    if (id.match(/(sameId_)(.)+/)) {
        console.log("matched");
    }
}​);​
```

where "sameId_" is a case sensitive representation of what you want to match.